# File on the server is populated, but is downloaded empty

Tags: php

I have an array of values that I want to put into a csv file and then download it:

```
$f = fopen("./tokens.csv", "w");
foreach ($tokens as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, array("1"=>$line));
}

fseek($f, 0);
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="tokens.csv"');
fpassthru($f);
```

The result is that the file on the server is populated with the contents of the token array, but the downloaded file is an empty csv file.

Comment: Is it empty or does it contain a PHP error message?

Comment: Try opening the file in "w+" mode

Comment: `header("Content-type: text/csv");` and NOT `header('Content-Type: application/csv');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've opened the file in "write-only" mode.  You didn't tell PHP that you wanted to read it.  You need to open the file in "read-write" mode.

```
$f = fopen("./tokens.csv", "w+");
```

DOCS: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

P.S. It's `text/csv` not `application/csv`.  Also you misspelled `attachment`.

---

NOTE: `"w+"` will overwrite the file each time.  Do you want to store the file on the server, or is this just a download script?  If you are *not* storing the file and you are just using this to download a file, you can just write to the output stream directly:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokens.csv"');

$f = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($tokens as $line) {
    fputcsv($f, array("1"=>$line));
}
```

Comment: Well, the file is populated, but it is still downloaded empty.

Comment: Attachment and NOT attachement , mime type is also wrong, for csv it's: `text/csv`

Comment: It's just a download script.

Comment: @TimZhukov-Khovanskiy: Then try my 2nd example.  It gets rid of the need for a temp file.

Comment: Your second example did work. I think the problem is either with synchronization or the file downloaded is not the one that's being populated.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$f = fopen("./tokens.csv", "w+");
foreach ($tokens as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, array("1"=>$line));
}

fseek($f, 0);
header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokens.csv"');
fpassthru($f);
```

`Attachment` and NOT `attachement`
The correct Mime type for CSV files is:
`header('Content-Type: text/csv');`